# Tag appearance in our tag warnings is broken; can't read them

Tags: bug, status-norepro, css, tag-warnings

Not a Stack bug. This bug was caused by [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup); I'll keep this around a while so the patch author can be informed.

---

Tag markup in our tag warnings is illegible, as you can probably see:

[image]

The text in those two tags is pale yellow on white and I can only barely make it out.

This is the [dungeons-and-dragons](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeons-and-dragons) tag warning. Here's a link that'll help you trigger it: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=dungeons-and-dragons. Click/focus the tag field then click/focus something outside it

I'm sure it wasn't like this 3½ weeks ago [when these tags warnings were added](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7358/1204), so it must be a very recent breakage. I tested both tag warnings at the time and would've pointed this out if things were this broken.

Comment: Following that link, the tag warnings are perfectly legible to me. They have the same colour scheme as the tags under the question body themselves. Maybe your browser is broken? I'm on Chrome.

Comment: @GreySage Thanks for checking. It looks like it's just one of my Stack userscripts, so I'll try to figure out which one.

Comment: Thanks for the report. I found the problem, or rather *two* problems: the style that's causing this really shouldn't be applied on RPG.SE, and it also shouldn't apply to tags at all. I'll push out a new SOUP version soon (probably tomorrow) that should fix this.