# Why are system tags treated different from other tags?

Tags: support, tags, questions

I may be misunderstanding the rules of the site here, but I somehow assimilated the ruling that it is not neccesary to state the system and edition in the question, if it is provided as a tag -- to the extend that I even removed "D&D 5e" from the title of questions tagged with [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e). Is this wrong?

For other tags, we do have guidance that the title and body of the question explicitly should include what the tag describes, [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7140/why-do-we-ask-for-the-body-of-the-question-to-demonstrate-the-tags-it-uses). The top scoring answer claims that system tags are an exception, because supposedly people look at those when answering, but it is not clear to me, why?

Comment: Related: [Is the Only-Tag Test for meta-tag-ness broken here?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5307/62294)

Comment: See also: [Are our implicit-information tagging practices becoming a problem?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5148/are-our-implicit-information-tagging-practices-becoming-a-problem)

Comment: This question should change to talk about the [specific question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/203627/why-would-a-monk-use-a-knuckle-duster) instead, I prematurely voted to reopen. The question should reflect that situation about the optimisation tag for people who lack the context.

Comment: I retract my reopen vote for now, because the question did not change yet.

Comment: @Akixkisu I agree that question is also one I did consider posing, but it is a separate one. I‘m fine with this one being closed as a double, and agreed to that.