# Investigation, clue or something else?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have tags for [clues](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clues) and [investigation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/investigation) and a smattering of other posts that [may be related](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=investigation). Is it possible to come up with a consoldiated tag that brings these together that serves a purpose?

Answer (score 3):

I'm very tempted to bring the hammer down on the proliferation of tags, but I think that impulse might be misplaced.

To reap the benefits of a folksonomy we really do need to leave it be, focusing attention just on the [harmful tags](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/411/what-are-the-meta-tags). I don't think redundant tags qualify as harmful: the only poor behaviour it encourages is slapping too many tags on a question, and that's not something that's going to get "out of hand" since it can be fixed whenever. Eventually it will be obvious which tags the community prefers (apart from the harmful ones, which should die by fire before then).

In the meantime: if in doubt, I say leave it be. When it's obvious that there's a better tag, make them synonyms.

Comment: I'm with SSD on leaving things be for a bit and letting the folksonomy do it's work. Then re-assess later.

Answer (score 0):

How about [mystery]? It implies other genre tags -- [horror], [science-fiction], [fantasy] -- so we should think about the precedent a bit.

Comment: Well except mystery as a genre of rpg is different than investigation/mystery as a part of a game. A genre breakdown might not be the right level of granularity.

Comment: That's true, hm.

Answer (score 0):

I think that perhaps people are gratuitously using tags.  I'm not sure how useful a tag "clues" is.  But sure, perhaps [investigation] (very similar to the fighting/combat thing - I was tempted to just delete the [fighting] tag...)