# What was the final verdict on spoilers?

Tags: discussion, tags, spoilers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should we worry about spoilers?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192/should-we-worry-about-spoilers)

This is a continuation/consoldation of [Should we worry about spoilers?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192/should-we-worry-about-spoilers), which has 2 answer tied for the highest voted spot. They can be summed up by "The Whole Site is a Spoiler Zone" versus "Use a Spoiler Tag."

We have 4 questions tagged [spoiler](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoiler), but spoiler is effectively a [meta-tag](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/411/what-are-the-meta-tags). Could we get a definitive yay-nay on the matter? Perhaps from a moderator?

Comment: We should keep discussion in the origianl post. Please comment/edit as necessary to drive discussion there.

Comment: agreed.  closing this one.